# spinner does not appear while a file upload is processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I want to show a spinner while uploading a video is processing
But after choosing a file spinner simply does not appear

**html**

```
<div class='spwrap' id='spwrap'>
<img class='spinner' src='spinner.gif' alt='img'>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.spwrap{
    display:none;
}
```

**js**

```
var spwrap = $('#spwrap'); // this is spinner wrap

inpfile.on('change', function(){
    spwrap.slideDown();  // doesn't slide
    var f = inpfile[0].files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('inpfile', f);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        async: false,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data);
            spwrap.slideUp();  // sometimes shortly slideDown and slideUp immediately
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
});
```

I also tried `spwrap.show()` instead of `slideDown` - the same result

how to solve this ?

**update**

I tried:

```
inpfile.on('change', function(){
    spwrap.slideDown();
    // the rest of code is removed
});
```

and it works i.e. `spwrap` is visible

Comment: must be a styling issue with `#spwrap` - what CSS do you use for the element?

Comment: @JaromandaX - of course - spinner is there - checked. `spwrap` is `display:none` by default

Comment: can you show the relevant HTML

Comment: @JaromandaX - I did, Please see my update at the end of post.